# is it safe to use proxy.config.json

Tags: angular

Does front end user or hackers can see my api url and headers. That I am proxing to the api server to get the data.

````
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
 "headers": {"Authorization": ----}
  }
}```
````

Comment: Nah that's just for the webpack dev server config. If you'd like reassurance you can always open your bundled js files after a prod build in the dist folder and do a search for like `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. So, how does it make a call to my API in production. Do in need to add somewhere in prod environment about my API details

Comment: You can't really prevent the user's browser from seeing The contents of requests it makes.